# I want to know to the SQL query about my ims system

Tags: mysql

[image]

How I can select all the product code which stock are less then minimal stock??

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please put your questions as text as much as possible. What have you tried on the query? Are you stuck on a particular aspect of the query? Because it looks like you want us to answer your homework question without trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_code FROM table WHERE stock < min_stock
```

Comment: It is just showing one row data from database. second or third one is not showing

Comment: Check to see if those rows are having stock value less than min_stock